# Reliability issue of HMC833 PLL

Tags: clock, pll, synthesizer

We are using an [HMC833LP6GE](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/hmc833.pdf) PLL in our design for generating 122.88 MHz from a reference of 100 MHz.

We are feeding a reference signal of >5 dBm. What we are observing is that out of 10 times, if we switch on and off (power supply) we are not getting output 2-3 times.

We are unable to get output for at least one time.

We are using an [NA-100M-6822](https://www.taitien.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/XO-0120_NA-100M-6800_Series.pdf) for generating the 100 MHz reference signal.

I have attached our schematic for your reference.

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far in your analysis? Does the PLL lock to the correct frequency in the good case and how does the spectrum at the output look like if it's not working? Do you get a signal at all or an unlocked PLL output?

Comment: @Don I am getting the output and PLL is locking. At random power on and off the PLL is not locking and I am not getting any output on the spectrum!

Comment: Have you checked the corresponding tune voltage in the bad case? Another option would be to exchange the PLL chip and see if the failure behaviour is still there

Comment: @Don we have assembled around 10 pcbs same issue with all of them.

Comment: What's up with all of the resistors in series with the control port wires? 1k ohms seems rather high. My guess would be that you're not reliably writing to the registers at power-up.

Comment: @DaveTweed Changed those 1k to 220R still the same! Got PLL locked for few times.. Then PLL is not locking

Comment: Why not bodge in something that allows you to force the ATTINY to reprogram the PLL again. Then when it doesn't power up correctly, see if reprogramming fixes things.  Otherwise check with the folk on the analog.com support forums and get them to check your register programming - there are many options on this chip.

Comment: @Tesla23 I have posted on the AD EZ forum no replies from any one!

Answer (score 0):

I am only speculating, but you have to get the timing right on power up between the PLL and the micro. From the HMC833 datasheet:

[image]

Are you waiting a sufficient amount of time before programming the chip? Have you tried a reset prior to programming as described?

I'd patch in some sort of button and change the micro code so that you can force the micro to program the PLL again, then when it fails on power up, check to see if reprogramming it makes it work.  If it then works then you have some sort of power-up timing issue with the micro and PLL reset.

Once you have evidence that you are programming the chip correctly and it still fails, I'd contact ADI.  I have found them responsive, but it is holiday season.

Comment: In HMC833 EVM, "CEN"(17th pin) Is connected to 3.3V through jumper and 100K strong pull down. I have provided 3.3V directly in my design. Now I replaced R172 with 0R and soldered a pull down resistor(100k). I getting output In all most all power on and Power off.I took reference of this question on AD forum https://ez.analog.com/clock_and_timing/f/q-a/534207/hmc833-can-t-lock-after-supply-power-off-power-on-at-high-temperature

Comment: The HMC833 "CEN" pin was floating until the 3.3V was generated?. Can you comment on this?

Comment: No idea, but note that on the eval board they connect it directly to 3.3V, you do via 10k. Probably unlikely to be a problem, unless you have a power-up sequencing issue - does 3.3V come up after the 5V, or does one of the data pins have power before your 3.3V?